# Knockoutjs treeview lazy loading: child nodes not showing

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I just started using knockoutjs and I'm trying to build a dynamic treeview. To simplify, I removed everything that's not related to the problem. the treeview will consist of nested UL-tags.

The html:

```
<div id="pnlDestinations">
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'GroupTemplate', foreach: Groups }"></ul>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="GroupTemplate">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-bind="text: GroupName, click: function() { RetrieveDestinations($data); }"></a>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'DestinationTemplate', foreach: Destinations }"></ul>
    </li>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="DestinationTemplate">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-bind="text: DestinationName"></a>
    </li>
</script>
```

The code:

```
function ViewModel(groups) {
    Groups = ko.mapping.fromJS(groups);
    RetrieveDestinations = function (group) {
        $.getJSON('GetDestinations?id=' + group.GroupId(), function (data) {
            group.Destinations(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
        });
    }
}

$(function () {
    $.getJSON("GetGroups", function (data) {
        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
    });
});
```

So I'm binding the treeview at two levels (using 2 templates), but i'm only retrieving one level in "GetGroups" (Destinations exists, but is an empty array).

Destinations are retrieved in the RetrieveDestinations() methods when the group is clicked and should replace the empty array in the group. However, they don't show up in my treeview.

The binding of the treeview should be correct because if I include the destinations in "GetGroups" everything is rendered correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ko.mapping.fromJS` when given an array is going to turn it into an observableArray.

So, when you do `group.Destinations(ko.mapping.fromJS(data))`, you are setting the value of the `Destinations` observableArray equal to an observableArray.  Basically, this just means that it is wrapped twice.

You could do something like `group.Destinations(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)())`

jsFiddle is not allowing saves at the moment, but here is your code simplified to use the mapping plugin to update the destinations (setTimeouts to simulate AJAX):

```
<div id="pnlDestinations">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: Groups">
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-bind="text: GroupName, click: $root.RetrieveDestinations"></a>
            <ul data-bind="foreach: Destinations">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-bind="text: DestinationName"></a>
                </li>        
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

ViewModel:

```
function ViewModel(groups) {
    this.Groups = ko.mapping.fromJS(groups);
    this.RetrieveDestinations = function (group) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            //fake data
            var name = group.GroupName(),
                data = [ 
                    { DestinationName: name + "-1" }, 
                    { DestinationName: name + "-2" },
                    { DestinationName: name + "-3" }
                ];
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, group.Destinations);
            group.Destinations.push({ DestinationName: "new" });
        }, 100);
    };
}

$(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var data = [
            { GroupName: "Group1", Destinations: [] },
            { GroupName: "Group2", Destinations: [] },
            { GroupName: "Group3", Destinations: [] }
            ];
        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
    }, 100);     
});
```

Comment: Yes, those two () did the trick, I now have a working treeview! Thanks a lot. Great explanation!

Comment: I noticed a strange side effect, RP Niemeyer... The code `group.Destinations.push({ DestinationId: 0, DestinationName: "New" });` doens't work. Message is: Object doesn't support property or method 'push'. It does work when I retrieve Destinations immediately.

Comment: Maybe you can put something in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Can you simulate ajax requests in jsFiddle? In the example above: if `group.Destinations(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)());` is followed by `group.Destinations.push({ DestinationId: 0, DestinationName: "New" });` (to immediatly add an extra item to the retrieved list) the exception is thrown on 'push'. If I don't replace the value of Destinations (comment it out) so it stays the original empty array, it works.

Comment: The updated code above (in answer) uses the mapping plugin to update the array using `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, group.Destinations)`.  Try this code.  I am not sure where you are doing your pushing, but see if this helps.  We can do it in a fiddle when jsFiddle allows saves again.

Comment: Amazing, really... your code is so much cleaner! I wonder why I thought I needed temlates in the first place :-/ In my defense: still learning knockoutjs. Your code worked, mine didn't. So thanks to you, I found out why: I changed the code in the 'GetGroups' service to return null as Destinations instead of an empty array. I used this value to test if I needed to call RetrieveDestinations. Testing if the array is empty would result in an ajax request each time the group was clicked if the group has no destinations at all.

Comment: So, in summary: replacing Destinations (value null) with a real array was good enough for the binding to kick in, but not for push() to work...